# Div takes up a new line instead of just taking up more vertical space

Tags: html, css

Here you can see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/

The problem is that I want the title of post #2 to not take up an entire new line. Instead, it should be right next to the thumbnail image and take up more vertical space.

How can I do this?

EDIT: It doesn't let me post this without adding some code, so here it is:

HTML

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="score">1</div>
    </div>

    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/"><div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/P84doIKb.jpg" />
    </div></a>

    <div class="text">
        <a href="http://example.org" class="title link">Title</a>
        <a href="http://example.org" class="domain">example.org</a>
        <div class="submitinfo">submitted 1 minute ago by <span>[username]</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="score">1</div>
    </div>

    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/"><div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/P84doIKb.jpg" />
    </div></a>

    <div class="text">
        <a href="http://example.org" class="title link">Veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very,very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long title that breaks it.</a>
        <a href="http://example.org" class="domain">example.org</a>
        <div class="submitinfo">submitted 1 minute ago by <span>[username]</span></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="vote">
        <div class="score">1</div>
    </div>

    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/"><div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/P84doIKb.jpg" />
    </div></a>

    <div class="text">
        <a href="http://example.org" class="title link">To clarify: the title above shouldn't move to a new line but instead take up more vertical space.</a>
        <a href="http://example.org" class="domain">example.org</a>
        <div class="submitinfo">submitted 1 minute ago by <span>[username]</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 55px;
    min-width: 530px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.item .vote{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #fdc;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}}
.item .vote .score{
    width: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.item .thumbnail{
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
.item .thumbnail img{
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
}

.item .text{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #cfd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
.item .text .title{
    font-size: 17px;
}
.item .text .domain{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.item .text .submitinfo{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

**css**

```
.item{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 55px;
    min-width: 530px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.item .vote{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #fdc;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    /*float: left;*/
}}
.item .vote .score{
    width: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.item .thumbnail{
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
.item .thumbnail img{
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
}

.item .text{
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    background-color: #cfd;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    /*float: left;*/
}
.item .text .title{
    font-size: 17px;
}
.item .text .domain{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.item .text .submitinfo{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/2/)

The problem is that you use `display:inline-block` and `float:left` in some elements instead of `display:table-cell` as you should.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I want to accept your answer but I have to wait. Stupid stackoverflow.

Comment: Follow-Up question: If I make the title very long (see #2 here: http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/3/) the title will move to the left, just below the image. How can I prevent this?
I want the title and the "example.org", "submitted 1 minute ago by [username]" to be strictly at the right side of the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

You should set max-width for the .text div. In my example, I set 300px. You can set more depends on your container.

```
.item .text{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #cfd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove display:inline-block and float:left from following classes:

1. .item .vote
2. .item .thumbnail
3. .item .text

Since your parent class ".item" is set to display:table so you have to set children with display:table-cell but In your classes display: inline-block overrides table-cell.

And there is no need to set float:left in display:table and display:table-cell as table-cells are aligned next to each other.

you final and corrected CSS will be:

```
    .item{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 55px;
    min-width: 530px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.item .vote{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #fdc;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.item .vote .score{
    width: 38px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.item .thumbnail{
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.item .thumbnail img{
    max-width: 70px;
    max-height: 70px;
}
.item .text{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #cfd;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.item .text .title{
    font-size: 17px;
}
.item .text .domain{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.item .text .submitinfo{
    color: #888888;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/9/

Comment: Looks solid, but why is the title of the first post moved to the right?

Comment: Yes Jonas there is width missing in ".item .text" class. like below:

.item .text{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #cfd;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 83%;
}

you can check it at [http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/14/](http://jsfiddle.net/sfhs6ra1/14/)